# Kafka JDBC sink decimal/numeric deserialization not supported?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am reading messages from a topic with a avro schema using the JDBC sink with as target postgres.

The messages are being delivered however the decimal/logical types are not being deserialized. I have looked for transformations to do this (none found) and read the in depth on connectors with JDBC (the numeric configs seem to apply to source connectors only).

Are users expected to deserialize logical types on the application level or write a custom transformer for decimal types? It seems like a common case.

I want to point the connector directly to the postgres db, so I would need to deserialize it to a NUMERIC type. How do you handle this with a sink connector i.e. bytes -> numeric or should I go from bytes to something else?